# Enterprise Architect UML Class Code Generation

Tags: java, code-generation, uml, reverse-engineering

I am working with EA (Ver 8.0858). I am trying to generate code based on two class diagrams. I would like it to output both to the same file since they are related and small. I can only get it to output code from one of the diagrams but not both. I have created the file manually and reverse engineered it back into EA as class diagrams. EA connects them with an association, but I cannot generate the code back into a single file, it only does one or the other. I am outputting to Java. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend managing the code by hand, and instead using tools to analyze/visualize it.  You will always find unwelcome limits in code generation tools like that, and their features will always lag emerging industry practices.

Comment: Not entirely true. Code generators can be as flexible as you need them to be. It's a matter of compromise. True, Enterprise Architect may have its limits, but you cannot judge all generators through EA.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. That is the conclusion I am coming to as well. It seems that UML is not set up to properly handle code generation in a way that can be useful. Most IDE's seem to better handle the code side of things. If anyone else has any comments regarding code generation in UML I would be glad to hear them.